# Entity Framework transaction for multiple raw update commands

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am new at using transaction of Entity Framework for Postgresql. I need to execute multiple `UPDATE` queries.

```
using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update table1 ....");
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update table2 ....");
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update table3 ....");

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

**Questions**:

1. Should I use `context.SaveChanges()` method for all update commands?
2. If table2 or table3 command fails, will table1 command rollback?

Comment: **(1)** - no, use just one call to `.SaveChanges()` before the `.Commit()`; **(2)** - yes, it an exception occurs, the transaction will be rolled back - so all changes made to that point will be rolled back

Comment: `SaveChanges` only saves changes that are made to entities tracked by the context, so there's no need to call it. The hard-coded update statements and `SaveChanges` are completely independent.